# Get lat long of the vertex drawn in DRAWVERTEX event leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

Get event coordinates on L.Draw.Event.DRAWVERTEX as i am not able to find any properties of the vertex

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.DRAWVERTEX, function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation, I found a place when the event is [fired](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js#L263). In the event payload, you can find all vertexes of your drawing poly-like shape. The last element of this collection is your coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your drawHandler - in the moment the DRAWVERTEX - Event is fired, you can look up the current position of your drawHandler

`this.drawHandler._currentLatLng.lat` and
`this.drawHandler._currentLatLng.lng`